# Métodos en POO con Java, impresión directa o retorno de valores

Tags: java, poo

Buen día tengo la siguiente duda; tengo un ejercicio de POO en Java el cual apenas estoy comenzando; mi duda es la siguiente

¿Por qué esto es válido?

```
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, int age, String email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }
    //ESTO FUNCIONA
    public void Presentarse(String name)
    {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Es decir hacer un `System.out.println()` dentro del método Presentarse; pero lo siguiente que hago no es válido

```
public void Presentarse(String name)
    {
        //ESTO NO FUNCIONA
        return name;
    }
```

Y me regresa el siguiente error

> Person.java:16: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
>                   return name;

Por que cuando he trabajado el PHP, por ejemplo dentro de la clase no genero ningún código que haga impresión directa de valores, eso lo trabajo por fuera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se nada de java pero como te dice el mensaje, no se espera ninguno valor de retorno. Estas declarando un método `void`. Es decir, no debe retornar valor. Sino deberías declararlo así:

```
public String Presentarse(String name)
    {
        return name;
    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: hay tienes razón amigo, se me paso totalmente inadvertido ese detalle pero tienes mucha razón

Comment: @shadow suele suceder! Hay que prestar atención a los errores y tratar de comprenderlos. Lo decía textualmente: `unexpected return value`. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El método al ser void "vacío" recibe un parámetro (en este caso string) el cual es utilizada dentro del método Presentarse, pero esta al ser void no generar una variable para retornar
Ej.

```
public void Presentarse(String name)
{
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Caso contrario que el método retorne un valor en vez de utilizar void se declara según el tipo de dato a retornar 
Ej.

```
public String Presentarse(String name)
{
    return name; //El tipo de dato de retorno debe ser igual al tipo de dato del metodo
}
```